# Apache POI does not shows hyperlinks in file

Tags: java, excel, apache

I have the following problem. I get code from example:

```
Hyperlink  link = createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_URL);
link.setAddress("https://google.com");
link.setLabel("xxxx");
row.createCell(0).setHyperlink(link);
```

But, when I open my xlsx file, I see empty cell. Other values are present. I'm using Apache POI 3.11, Libre Office on Windows 7. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `link.setLabel("xxxx");` method, you should use `cell.setValue("xxxx")` instead:

```
Hyperlink  link = createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_URL);
link.setAddress("https://google.com");
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setHyperlink(link);
cell.setCellValue("xxxx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast createHelper as such: (Hyperlink) createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_URL);